# WizardNewFileCreationPage order

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, wizard

I'm creating an Export wizard, including the possibility for the user to choose the format of the export and then to choose the location of the export with WizardNewFileCreationPage.

To do so, I've created 3 pages, one extending wizardPage with a radio to set the next page to call, and 2 others pages pending the format and extending WizardNewFileCreationPage.

It's working almost perfectly, my only problem concerns the "Finish" button, which requires to be clickable that all export format are fulfilled even if I overrided the function isPageComplete to limit the page validation only to the function validatePage.

It looks like the function validatePage doesn't valid only it's own control but also all the control implemented by the class WizardNewFileCreationPage in the Wizard.

Am I going wrong somewhere and does anybody know a solution ?

Regards,
Waldo

Comment: Which function `validatePage`?

Comment: The function in WizardNewFileCreationPage

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. Of course the WizardNewFileCreationPage validatePage validates everything on that page.

Comment: I mean, in my wizard there is two WizardNewFileCreationPage, one implemented for XML export and one implemented for CSV export. However, if I want to press the "Finish" button, eclipse needs both the CSV and XML export pages fulfilled and not only the XML page or the CSV page while these two page are totally independant :x
My point on validatePage function is that it's not validating only the WizardNewFileCreationPage that is the CurrentPage but that it looks like it's validating all the WizardnewFileCreationPage contained in the Wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WizardDialog` showing the dialog drives button enablement. At various points it calls its `updateButtons` method. This in turn calls the `Wizard` `canFinish` method to set the Finish button state.

The default for `canFinish` is to call the `WizardPage` `isPageComplete` method for **every** page even for pages which are not currently active.

For `WizardNewFileCreationPage` the `isPageComplete` method consults the result of the `validatePage` method.

So you can override the `Wizard` `canFinish` method to only test the pages you care about. Or you can override the individual page `isPageComplete` methods to return the result you want.

Comment: That's the best explanation! :) 
Thank you for taking your time on my problem greg :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I think my problem came from the fact I wasn't implementing canFinish method that's requires in it's default implementation that all page contained in the Wizard are fulfilled. To avoid my problematic, I did it this way :

```
@Override
public boolean canFinish() {
    if (this.getContainer().getCurrentPage() == mainPage)
        return false;
    return this.getContainer().getCurrentPage().isPageComplete();
}
```

*Note : My "mainPage" attribute is theone defining the format of the export and then the nextPage to use.*

Also, I kept verifying if my page was complete this way by calling the WizardNewFileCreationPage this way :

```
@Override
public boolean isPageComplete() {
    return this.validatePage();
}
```